# Control Panel: Staying on the same tab when switching sites

Tags: control-panel

Control Panel: Staying on the same tab when switching sites

Our client has a site in two languages. The field layout of one of the sections is set up with four different tabs.

When editing content in the second tab of an entry the URL is `…/entries/people/355-john-smith?site=de#tab02--publications` for the German site. When switching to English we end up at the first tab (URL: `…/entries/people/355-john-smith?site=en`). Is there a setting to have the anchor (`#tab02--publications`) added to the site switcher link? Or would I need to find a hacky Javascript solution with the *Control Panel JS* plugin?

Craft version 4.7.3

---

The issue [Keep entry tab opened while switching sites #4018](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/4018) addresses just this and apparently was solved in Craft 3.5.6. But the issue has reappeared for us.

Answer (score 1):

[Craft 4.7.4](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/4018#issuecomment-1960406719) solves the problem.